# Difference between sharing and publishing my google app script library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a library and i have to share this with all my colleagues. They will use it call various methods defined in that library. So, should i publish this as add-on or i have to share the link with everyone ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make your project a library so other can use it as such, I would just create it as a library, you can look how to create and use libraries in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

If you want to share your code so other people can modify the source code you can make it as such with the File>Share button, you can take a further look at this in the [collaborating page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating).

Finally if you want to know what you can do with deployments you can investigate in [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments)